# Download working only after reloading page (node.js)

Tags: node.js, express

I'm passing a filepath from jade back to server side. It works ok, except, I need to reload the page if I want a download to start. I suppose the filepath gets back to index.js too late? Is there a workaround?

**index.js**

```
router.get('/download', function(req, res){
    var file = req.query.name;
    res.download(file);
});
```

**index.jade**

```
a(href="/download?name=" +encodeURIComponent(parentFiles[j].children[i].path))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use headers instead of this default res.download

```
var path = require('path');
var mime = require('mime');

app.get('/download', function(req, res){

  var file = req.query.name;

  var filename = path.basename(file);
  var mimetype = mime.lookup(file);

  res.setHeader('Content-disposition', 'attachment; filename=' + filename);
  res.setHeader('Content-type', mimetype);

  var filestream = fs.createReadStream(file);
  filestream.pipe(res);
});
```